# Is there a meaningful metric on the set of logical formulas?

Tags: logic, metric-spaces

Let's say $\phi$ is the set of all formulas in classical logic over the propositions $p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots$

I'm wondering whether there is there a metric that can measure the "similarity" between any two formulas in $\phi$.

By "similar" I mean that they have more or less the same structure OR that their satisfying assignments are somehow related.

Comment: For a semantic example, letting $\mu$ be the natural measure on the space of valuations for $\{p_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, we can consider the function $$d(\varphi,\psi)=\mu(\{v: v\models\neg(\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi)\}).$$ Basically, how likely is it for $\varphi$ and $\psi$ to have different truth values?

Comment: For a structural example, since any classical logic formula can be considered a rooted tree with labelled leaves and edges, you should look at "Boorman, S. A., & Olivier, D. C. (1973). Metrics on spaces of finite trees. Journal of Mathematical Psychology, 10(1), 26–59".  https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2496(73)90003-5